# Planned maintenance scheduled for Saturday, February 19, 2022 at 2:00AM UTC (Friday, February 18, 2022 at 9:00PM US/EST)

Tags: discussion, announcements, maintenance

**tl;dr** Planned service interruption that will impact all Stack Exchange sites, Jobs, and Chat. All sites may be read-only for up to 2 hours on Saturday, February 19, 2022 at 2:00AM UTC (Friday, February 18, 2022 at 9:00PM US/ET). On-premises Enterprise instances will not be affected.

### Short Version

There will be a service degradation for up to 2 hours on Saturday, [February 19, 2022 at 2:00AM UTC (Friday, February 18, 2022 at 9:00PM EST)](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingdetails.html?year=2022&month=2&day=19&hour=2&min=0&sec=0&p1=224&p2=75&p3=179&p4=136&p5=240). During that time, questions and answers will still display, job listings will still work, and job ads will still display. **However, the site will be "read only," i.e. people won't be able to add/edit new job listings, apply for jobs, post, edit, or vote on questions/comments/answers; reputation won't change, etc.** This should minimize the disruption to the majority of casual readers. We will display a banner on the sites stating we're read-only for maintenance.

### Longer Version

#### What we’ll be doing

SQL Server has a large number of features which can interact in surprising ways. In this case, the sparse columns feature prevents us from adding new non-null columns with a default value as an online, metadata-only change. We are removing sparse columns from some tables to make changes easier without further outages.

We expect that the site will be in a read-only state for less than two hours in total. Once we have made our changes and everything seems to be up and running, we’ll restore functionality.

### Questions or concerns?

Please post a comment or answer below; we’ll do our best to answer any concerns between now and the maintenance window.

Comment: I like that you have a tl;dr, a short version, and a long version, all of which are about the same length

Comment: @Cullub Maybe they build up -- so you have to read the "tl;dr" first before you get the rest ;)

Comment: Hah! Truthfully, it's a template and I just put the words in the template.

Comment: [With your hands?!](https://xkcd.com/1296/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Migration complete**

On February 18, 2022 at 9:41 PM EST US (February 19, 2022 at 2:41 AM UTC), we completed migration and returned the site to read-write mode. Thanks for your patience!